# Laravel dissociate for hasOne relation

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

For a `belongsTo` relationship, I can use `dissociate`, but what is the equivalent for `hasOne`?

Ex. `Phone` belongs to `User`:

```
$phone->user()->dissociate(); // success
$user->phone()->dissociate(); // fail
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is no reverse equivallent.

Since

```
$user->phone()
```

returns an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne` object, lets take a look on [that file](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOne.php) - there is no [dissociate()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.php#L259) equivallent method. But `HasOne` extends `HasOneOrMany`, so just to be shure let's take a [look on that too](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php). Still nothing.